# If $x$ is integral over $A_m$ for all maximal ideals $m$, then $x$ is integral over $A$

Tags: commutative-algebra, integral-dependence

I am going over an old exam, and there is this question that I am stuck:

> Given $A$ a commutative ring with unity, show that if $x\in\operatorname{Frac}(A)$  is integral over $A_m$ for all maximal ideals $m$ of $A$, then $x$ is integral over $A$.

Can anyone give me a hint please?

Comment: First explain (mainly to yourself) what is $\;A\;$ , where is $\;x\;$ taken from...

Comment: @DonAntonio sorry, I didn't re-read what I wrote to see if I provided full information.

Comment: Thanks @user1412 ...but still: if $\;A\;$ is *not* an integer domain, then by Frac$\,(A)\;$ you must mean the ring of fractions of $\;A=S^{-1}A\;$ , with $\;S\;4 the set of all non-zero divisors. If $\;A\;$ is an ID, then the above localization is just its fractions field.

Answer (score 4):

Consider the map of $A$-modules $f:\bar{A}\rightarrow \bar{A}[x]$, where $\bar{A}$ is the integral closure of $A$ in its field of fractions. This is onto if and only if $f_\mathfrak{m}:\bar{A}_\mathfrak{m}\rightarrow \bar{A}_\mathfrak{m}[x]$ is onto at all maximal ideals $\mathfrak{m}$ of $A$ (see for instance prop. 3.9 in Atiyah, MacDonald).

Comment: @user121097: because $(A[x])_\mathfrak{m}= A_\mathfrak{m}\otimes A[x]$

Answer (score 2):

For each $\mathfrak m$, choose an $f \notin \mathfrak m$ such that $x$ is integral over $A_f$ (for instance, a common multiple of the denominators of the coefficients in a minimal equation for $x$ over $A_\mathfrak m$). Then the $f_\mathfrak m$'s generate the unit ideal in $A$, since no maximal ideal can contain all $f_\mathfrak m$'s by construction. Let $f_1, \dots, f_n$ be a finite subset of the $f$'s which generates the unit ideal.

Let $M=A[x]\subseteq \text{Frac}(A)$, considered as an $A$-module. Then $M_{f_i} = A_{f_i}[x]$ is a finite $A_{f_i}$-module for each $i$, because $x$ is integral over $A_{f_i}$. Since the $f_i$'s generate the unit ideal, it follows by a standard "patching" argument that $M$ is itself a finite $A$-module, hence $x$ is integral over $A$.

Comment: you are right, my answer would not do. +1.

Comment: @adbrido Hmm, I think that your answer was actually fine after the last edit. Going to bed now, I'll sleep on it!

Comment: I think $x*f_i$ will be integral over A. Some of the $f_i's$ generate the unit ideal in A, then just add those $a_i * xf_i$ to get x, hence x is integral over A (the sum of integral elements is integral).

Comment: @user1412 Ah, yes, that works too!

Comment: @Bruno: yes, after the last edit it works. I'll put it back. thanks!